# How to find in javascript with regular expression string from url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Good evening, How can I find in javascript with regular expression string from url address for example i have url: http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/mikronebulizer/ and I need only string between last slashes (/ /) http://something.cz/something/string/ in this example word that i need is mikronebulizer. Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex match with a group.

Use this:

```
/([\w\-]+)\/$/.exec("http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/mikronebulizer/")[1];
```

[Here's a jsfiddle showing it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/qH2c5/2/)

This part: `([\w\-]+)`

- Means at least 1 or more of the set of alphanumeric, underscore and hyphen and use it as the first match group.

Followed by a `/`

And then finally the: `$`

- Which means the line should ***end*** with this

The .exec() returns an array where the first value is the full match (IE: "mikronebulizer/") and then each match group after that.

- So `.exec()[1]` returns your value: mikronebulizer

Comment: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." - You're not escaping your slash in your regex.

Comment: What if there is a hyphen between last slashes, i try it, for example: /spotrebni-material/ alert shows only material without spotrebni. Is there workaround for this ? Thank you

Comment: @user3242334 I updated the regex in the post and the jsfiddle example to include hyphen. Just add it to the match: ([\w\-]+)

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
url.match(/([^\/]*)\/$/);
```

Should do it.

If you want to match (optionally) without a trailing slash, use:

```
url.match(/([^\/]*)\/?$/);
```

See it in action here: http://regex101.com/r/cL3qG3

Comment: You should probably include the possibility of matching it without a slash at the end, such as "`http://foo.bar/baz/quux`"

Comment: Indeed - you could make the slash non greedy like so `([^\/]*)\/?$`.

Comment: and, an explanation is always nice

Answer (score 0):

If you have the url provided, then you can do it this way:

```
var url = 'http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/mikronebulizer/';
var urlsplit = url.split('/');
var urlEnd = urlsplit[urlsplit.length- (urlsplit[urlsplit.length-1] == '' ? 2 : 1)];
```

This will match either everything after the last slash, if there's any content there, and otherwise, it will match the part between the second-last and the last slash.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to consider - yes a pure RegEx approach might be easier (heck, and faster), but I wanted to include this simply to point out `window.location.pathName`.

```
function getLast(){
    // Strip trailing slash if present
    var path = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$?/, '');
    return path.split('/').pop();
}
```

Comment: How is the pathname to the current url relevant to getting the last part of a given url? In this example, can't you just replace the `window.location.pathname` with `'http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/mikronebulizer/'`?

Comment: @Joeytje50 Right, well for this particular example it's not particularly helpful *because* op wants only the last path segment.  However I think a lot of JS newcomers don't know that you can access individual parts of the URL directly using the `window.location` object.  So included it here for reference.

Comment: Addendum: `var link = document.createElement('a'); link.href = url` , and you can enjoy `link.pathname`.

Comment: @Zirak Yep, that's a great tool in our collective arsenals!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could get using `split`:

```
var pieces = "http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/mikronebulizer/".split("/");

var lastSegment = pieces[pieces.length - 2];

// lastSegment == mikronebulizer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var url = 'http://www.odsavacky.cz/blog/wpcproduct/mikronebulizer/';
    if (url.slice(-1)=="/") {
      url = url.substr(0,url.length-1);
    }
    var lastSegment = url.split('/').pop();
    document.write(lastSegment+"<br>");
```