# Passing variables to Javascript from "pretty" URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, url

My problem is, I would like to create "pretty" URLs for visitors that look like this:

http://domain.com/Name

I have users that often send friends to my service, and I have been created customized pages for each one with the person's First Name in the headline.  E.g., "John, here's an easy way to fix this widget"

I then save the page as an index.html file in a custom folder so the link structure for the custom page is domain/Name with Name being their First Name.

This is getting tedious and I would love to use Javascript to automate the process.  However, the only documentation I can find on passing variables to Javascript involves "ugly" domains such as domain/jspass2.html?FirstName=John&LastName=Smith

Is there a way to beautify these domains and still pass the variables to a javascript code that inputs their name into the html code?  I don't want to "cloak" an ugly domain (using a href, for example)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) if your web server is Apache.

Comment: Seeing as you tagged this question with PHP, I'd suggest doing this server side as well. We'd need to know a little bit about your setup, though, to provide an answer to suit.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could make it "prettier" by making the querystring cleaner.

example:

http://www.domain.com/?John,Smith

The javascript in your index file can read that.

```
var getQueryString = function() {
    queryString = window.location.search;
    queryStringCleaned = queryString.substring(queryString.indexOf('?') + 1 );

    return queryStringCleaned;
};
```

Comment: I suppose that would work.  I only need the first name, so it would look like http://www.domain.com/?John.  Can you direct me towards some info on how to pull that variable into the javascript?  And just so I can wrap my head around it, the question mark delineates between the normal URL and the variables, correct?  Couldn't you just tell the javascript how many characters there will be, and the variable starts after that?  E.g., the domain will always be the same; http://domain.com/.  Can you tell it to start reading after 11 characters?

Comment: queryString.indexOf('?') is equal to the position of the question mark in the url. Substring will grab the contents of the url from the position after the question mark to the end. It is best to use this rather than saying 11 characters, because it accounts for a possible change in the url (even it is going to be the same). Program defensively!

Answer (score 0):

if "http://domain.com/Name" is your domain, variable firstName will have the value "Name".

```
var firstName = window.location.pathname.match(/([\w-]+)\/?.*/)[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just take the whole URL in JS, and parse it "by hand". Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492117/how-to-find-in-javascript-with-regular-expression-string-from-url) regex (for example) to find the parameters passed.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Paul, I wrote you something that extracts the first name field from the url you provided. If the format is consistent, and you can obtain the url in javascript, you can use this. You may possibly have to create the page first, then redirect the user because javascript is a client side language and the page will already be rendered.

```
var url = "domain/jspass2.html?FirstName=John&LastName=Smith";
url = url.slice(url.indexOf("FirstName=") + 10, url.length);
url = url.slice(0, url.indexOf("&"));
```